# Fail while publishing API to swaggerhub

Tags: swaggerhub

As part of our CI we publish API to swaggerhub via swaggerhub-cli using swaggerhub api:publish. We have several microservices and for some of them it works fine and we can see the log like Published API ****/service_name/version. But for some others, it fails with the following error: Error: Unknown API ****/service_name:version.
The code for services **is the same**.
So the issue with replacing "/" symbol with ":" symbol.
I went through the UI directly but found nothing related to projects' configurations.

```
swaggerhub api:publish ${SWAGGER_OWNER}/${params.businessAppName}/${pipelineParameters.businessAppVersion}
```

Comment: I suggest contacting [SwaggerHub support](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/message/).

Comment: Seems like we found the root cause. The issue was with commented plugin
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swaggerhub-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> -->
It is uncommented for "work" services.